# What does OAuth 1.0 realm stand for?

Tags: oauth

> The OPTIONAL realm parameter is added and interpreted per [RFC2617], section 1.2. [[OAuth 1.0]](http://oauth.net/core/1.0/)

What is the difference between a request with and without a realm field?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Provider basically decides if this is of any importance. It is the counterpart of the WWW-authenticate response header. If a sever returns a WWW-authenticate header of 'OAuth realm="https://api.example.com"' then it probably parses that value from the Authenticate request header in the OAuth process.

These headers have a more direct implication when using HTTP-basic authentication since all browsers support this.

When using OAuth and WWW-authenticate header it is mostly good form I would say. With the added benefit of not having API responses cached in proxies/nodes across the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

> The authentication parameter realm is defined for all authentication
> schemes:
>
> ```
>   realm       = "realm" "=" realm-value
>   realm-value = quoted-string
> ```
>
> The realm directive (case-insensitive) is required for all
> authentication schemes that issue a challenge. The realm value
> (case-sensitive), in combination with the canonical root URL (the
> absoluteURI for the server whose abs_path is empty; see section 5.1.2
> of [2]) of the server being accessed, defines the protection space.
> These realms allow the protected resources on a server to be
> partitioned into a set of protection spaces, each with its own
> authentication scheme and/or authorization database. The realm value
> is a string, generally assigned by the origin server, which may have
> additional semantics specific to the authentication scheme. Note that
> there may be multiple challenges with the same auth-scheme but
> different realms.

**Source**: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617